# What is DH- stopping?

Tags: phonetics, dental-fricative

I can't seem to find any information on the internet that doesn't confuse me. But basically, is DH-stopping when in words such as 'there' - the 'th' is pronounced as a /d/? so 'dere'

Thanks!

Comment: Where have you ever seen anybody writing about "DH-stopping"? It's a made-up expression and not a linguistic term, so you can't tell without seeing how it's used. I could be it's about *th* being pronounced [d] or [d̪].

Comment: @user6726 I've seen it quite a bit in discussion of English (and generally Germanic) dialects. For example:  
http://www.lancaster.ac.uk/fss/projects/linguistics/innovators/documents/Iclave4_Torgersenetal_000.pdf  
http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1054&context=pwpl  
https://web.stanford.edu/class/linguist156/Eckert_2008.pdf  
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4586846/

Answer (score 5):

"Th-stopping", in general, is when a dental fricative (/θ ð/, written as "th" in English) turns into a dental or alveolar stop (/t d/). This is currently happening in many dialects of English and has historically happened in the other Germanic languages: compare English "brother", "mother" with their German cognates, *Bruder*, *Mutter*.

The general process seems to be that the dental fricatives first become dental stops, which preserves the distinction between words like "die" and "thy" (the former is pronounced with an alveolar stop, the latter with a dental). Then later, the distinction between dental and alveolar stops collapses, so "die" and "thy" become true homophones.

"Dh-stopping" is a particular type of "th-stopping". "Dh" is a poor-man's way of writing /ð/; "dh-stopping" affects /ð/ (as in "thy") but not /θ/ (as in "thigh"). This is less common than both being affected, but for example several London dialects and some types of AAVE feature "dh-stopping" and "th-fronting" (/θ/ merges with /f/).