# The "th" sound as a plosive in British dialects

Tags: english, phonology, historical-linguistics, dialects, dental-fricative

I've noticed that the *th* sound often becomes a plosive sound in *Appalachian English*. When and how did this phenomenon start?The only case I know where this happens in the british isles is *Irish*.Does it also happen in other dialects on the island of Great Britain?

Comment: See also: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/25546/what-is-dh-stopping

Comment: As pointed out in the link above, it's very common everywhere in the world where English is spoken. It happens because English /t/ and /d/ are actually alveolar and not dental (this is a major feature of English accents in other languages that do have dental /d/ and /t/ phonemes). This means that they can contrast with a dental stop, and the interdental fricatives /θ ð/ can both be relaxed to stops without losing contrast. It takes a lot more effort to make /θ ð/ than it does to make /t d/ and that's all that's needed.

Comment: @jlawler I'm not sure that it's always easier to produce [t̪ d̪...] than it is to produce [θ ð]. Intervocalically, it seems like the latter is easier (fricatives in general are easier to produce than stops in these cases), particularly the voiced ones. /d/ is realized as [ð] a lot more frequently than /ð/ to [d̪]; Finnish serves as an example of this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Th-stopping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th-stopping) has always been a distinctive feature of Irish English, where the phonological distinction between [t] and [t̪], [d] and [d̪] is mostly maintained. It is not characteristic of most varieties of English in either England or Wales; urban and working-class English speech in southern England prefers [th-fronting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th-fronting) instead.

However, young urban English in England, not limited to modern Multicultural London English (MLE), is tending more towards a complete merger of /θ/ into [t] and /ð/ into [d], conventionally called [th-alveolarisation](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XhcwDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36) but often subsumed under the above. The effect is stronger with the definite article `the` and determiners `this`, `that`, and is usually attributed to Caribbean and AAVE influence on MLE and the speech of other English urban areas, and is becoming more common among [speakers of different ethnicities](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/303549511_Word_initial_th-stopping_among_urban_British_youth).

Rural Irish accents also have this complete merger, and this may have been the source of th-stopping/alveolarisation for many English phonologies across the North American continent, notably in [Newfoundland English](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WO6qBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA160), where it is attested from the late 18th-century.

In Scotland, th-stopping is mainly found in Glasgow and in rural communities (e.g. the [Shetlands](https://orca.cf.ac.uk/38673/1/SmithDurhamAmericanSpeech.pdf)), and is [attributed](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FJ7dAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA48) to Irish/Ulster influence; th-fronting is more common overall; th-debuccalisation (where /θ/ and /ð/ become [h]) is distinctive to Scotland. This is most probably the source of th-stopping/alveolarisation in Appalachian English: [Ulster Scots](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=--y1kBBiPlIC&pg=PA203), although there are relatively few historical records of the speech.

However, it is to be mentioned that th-stopping has been a tendency for a long time - at least since the first few centuries CE in Germanic (the [Second High German Consonant Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_German_consonant_shift#/%CE%B8/_%3E_/d/_(phase_4))): across Dutch, Low and High German and continental Scandinavian, but not Icelandic or English (Faroese lost it subsequently and separately). Compare German `der` with English `the`, German `Dorn` with English `thorn`, German `Tod` with English `death`.

Even in Early Modern English of the early 17th century, the tendency to merge into /t/ and /d/ was ever present, such that certain mergers were accepted into the standard, e.g. English `murder` vs Icelandic `morð`, English `burden` vs Icelandic `byrði`. Shakespeare himself used the "th" variant in Othello in 1622 (Act I, Scene 2):

> Yet do I hold it very stufe of Conscience
>
> To doe no contriu'd mur**th**er

... but in the 1623 printing, it is uses mur**d**er.

By the 18th century, the th-alveolarised form in this case has won out in London at least. From *The Beggar's Opera* (1728):

> You never had a finer, braver set of Men than at present. We have not had a Mur**d**er among them all, these seven months.

The question *why* is always tricky in diachronic studies, and I think articulatory phonetics does play a role, but it's often hard to pin down what "effort" means. There is also the auditory/perceptual phonetics - somewhat less well-studied. Language contact is also a major factor, and cross lingustically /θ/ and /ð/ are pretty rare (and not really found in modern Standard Irish nor in Ulster Gaelic - it was lost after Old Irish via debuccalisation, but the modern orthography of Irish still makes reference to it).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Corrected! Although in general Cockney, th-fronting did win out!